# Vaadin Eclipse plugin compile widgetset logLevel

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin7

Very simple question, I need to know how to set the logLevel for the Vaadin plugin call to Compile Widgetset in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it. For anyone interested, go to Project|Properties, select Vaadin from the tree on the left, and add whatever parameters you need, in my case:`-logLevel TRACE -strict`